# How to make emacs work well with tiling window managers?

Tags: frames, fullscreen

Under some conditions Emacs will try to resize a frame if its not fullscreen or maximized.

(specifically `default-text-scale`, but I don't think its the only one).

This sends window-manager window (aka Emacs frame) resize commands, which get ignored, making the frame flicker when scaling fonts for eg.

Running `toggle-frame-maximized` solves this until the window manager moves the frame which resets Emacs internal state.

I tried:

```
(add-to-list
  'default-frame-alist 
  '(fullscreen . maximized))
```

Which works at startup until the frame is moved.

---

How to configure Emacs so it's always maximized, or so that plugins don't think it's possible to resize the frame?

*Tested with spectrwm and notion window managers.*

Comment: I suggest that you mention which window manager you are using.

Comment: You might want to set `frame-resize-pixelwise` to `t`, as it will prevent the window from resizing according to font size. It works well for me with dwm.

Comment: @mikado notion / spectrwm, @DoMiNeLa10 doesn't resolve issue w/ `default-text-scale`

Comment: Are you using the newest version of Emacs? Double buffering got added recently, and it effectively gets rid of flickering.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 version `26.1`

Comment: Can you give some command that triggers the resize?

Comment: `default-text-scale-increase` - but flickering is mainly noticeable if you call many times, say if you bind to Ctrl-Wheel.

Comment: Where does `default-text-scale` come from?  I don't see it when using `emacs -Q`.

Comment: See: https://github.com/purcell/default-text-scale